# Switch with enum and multiple return

Tags: c#, filter, enums, switch-statement, multiple-return-values

I have two objects:

```
public enum BugReportStatus
{
    OpenUnassigned = 0,
    OpenAssigned = 1,
    ClosedAsResolved = 2,
    ClosedAsRejected = 3
}
```

and

```
public enum BugReportFilter
{
    Open = 1,
    ...
    Closed = 4,
}
```

And I would like to create a `switch case` where depending on the `BugReportFilter` choose my output will be a specific `BugReportStaus`.

So I created a method `CheckFilter`

```
private BugReportStatus Checkfilter(BugReportFilter filter)
{
    switch (filter)
    {
        case BugReportFilter.Open:
            return BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned;

        case BugReportFilter.Closed:
            return BugReportStatus.ClosedAsResolved;
    }
};
```

The problem is that in the case of a `BugReportFilter.Open` option I should return `BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned` **AND** `BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned`, is there a way to concat this two options in a single return ?

Comment: then return type may be ``Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`` or ``List<T>``

Comment: Either use an array as return object or use an `Enum` with `[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: The only way I can see is if you made it `Flags`, but logically the two are distinct, so I think that's not a good way to go. using some form of multiple values in the return would probably be best, i.e. an array, list, or what have you.

Comment: look up how to return multiple flags and parse them, then you can return BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned & BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return `IEnumerable<BugReportStatus>`:

```
private IEnumerable<BugReportStatus> Checkfilter(BugReportFilter filter)
{
    switch (filter)
    {
        case BugReportFilter.Open:
            return new[]{ BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned, BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned };

        case BugReportFilter.Closed:
            return new[]{ BugReportStatus.ClosedAsResolved };
    }
};
```

Then you could use `Enumerable.Contains` to check if it's f.e. `BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned`:

```
bool isOpenAssigned = Checkfilter(someFiler).Contains(BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned);
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the options power of two, e.g.

```
public enum Flags
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4
}
```

then return `Flags.B | Flags.A` from your function (the return type should be `int`).

Here is how to check if flag is set

```
bool isA = (enumFlag & Flags.A) != 0; // true means A is set
```

For more info, please see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396851/Ending-the-Great-Debate-on-Enum-Flags).

Comment: This is usually a good option, but I don't like it with the example provided. How can a bug be both 'assigned' and 'unassigned' at the same time?

Comment: Technically 0 isn't a power of 2.

Comment: @Steve Return type better be int

Comment: How do you know that I have set the Flags.A if you return Flags.A | Flags.B The return is 1 also if I set only Flags.B

Comment: @Steve You AND result with the flag you are interested in

Comment: Usually you'd name the 0 Flag to None and it's a special case.

Comment: Well, now is more correct, still with this change you need to change the return type of the function from an enum to an int because if I set Flag.A | Flag.B there is no Flag enum with the value of 3. For this kind of work the Enums has the special [Flags Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Steve I haven't worked with Flags attribute, will not changing return type to int work?

Comment: Yes of course it will work, but it is ... how to say?... less polished? less elegant.... Not a big deal.

Comment: @Steve Ok, I also found an article with explanations, I will post it to OP.

Comment: That's what the [Flags attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. And the way to test is `bool isA = enumFlag.HasFlag(Flags.A);`

Answer (score 3):

For your case, I recommend to represent the return in different bits (using concept of flags) so that you can concat the return:

```
public enum BugReportStatus
{
    OpenUnassigned = 1, //0000 0001
    OpenAssigned = 2, //0000 0010
    ClosedAsResolved = 4, //0000 0100
    ClosedAsRejected = 8 //0000 1000
}
```

Thus you could do this:

```
    switch (filter)
    {
        case BugReportFilter.Open:
            return BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned + BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned; //return 3

        case BugReportFilter.Closed:
            return BugReportStatus.ClosedAsResolved;
    }
```

And change your return type to something like `int`:

```
private int Checkfilter(BugReportFilter filter)
```

And to check the result outside, simply check what flag exist in the `int` return

Comment: Ian, is there a reason for doing it this way instead of with Flags?

Comment: @DrewJordan no, you could use the `Flags` attribute as well. The concept is the same. It is just in my code you don't use attribute.

Comment: OK, it never occurred to me to implement it myself in this way, was curious if there were times that this would be more appropriate to use. thanks.

Comment: @DrewJordan if you are more familiar with using `[Flags]` attribute and you only use `C#`, then there is really no need to bother this kind of style. :) it just help me to have common concept of having flags for multiple return with or without `[Flags]` attribute because I am not always coding in C#. The same concept and, to certain extend, similar writing style can be applied to other language than C# which does not recognize `[Flags]` attribute. I think, it is partially a matter of familiarity too.

Answer (score 1):

what about returning an enumerable?

```
private IEnumerable<BugReportStatus> Checkfilter(BugReportFilter filter)
{
    switch (filter)
    {
        case BugReportFilter.Open:
            return new List<BugReportStatus>()
            {
                BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned,
                BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned
            };

        case BugReportFilter.Closed:
            return new List<BugReportStatus>()
            {
                BugReportStatus.ClosedAsResolved,
                BugReportStatus.ClosedAsRejected
            };

        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to accomplish this. To use this you need to increase your enum values for `BugReportStatus` by powers of 2 as the enum is treated as a bit field. You also need to decorate the enum with the `[Flags]` attribute. E.g.

```
[Flags]
public enum BugReportStatus
{
    OpenUnassigned = 1,
    OpenAssigned = 2,
    ClosedAsResolved = 4,
    ClosedAsRejected = 8
}
```

You can then return multiple values such as: `return BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned | BugReportStatus.OpenUnassigned;`

You can use the [`Enum.HasFlags`](http://Enum.HasFlags) method to check if a specific bit field has been set. E.g.

```
Checkfilter(BugReportFilter.Open).HasFlag(BugReportStatus.OpenAssigned) // true
Checkfilter(BugReportFilter.Open).HasFlag(BugReportStatus.ClosedAsResolved) // false
```